# Python sources on an http site, or in ISO image?

Tags: virtualbox, unix, python, iso-image, sco-unix

I installed *SCO UnixWare 7.1.4* on *VirtualBox*.

This installation does not include `Python.`

I want to download the *Python 2.7/2.6 source tar-ball* from `ftp.python.org.`

however:

1. Anonymous FTP is not possible on `ftp.python.org`
2. The installation's `lynx` does not support SSL, and trying to download from `http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7/Python-2.7.tgz` switches to an HTTPS connection.

**Are Python sources available on an HTTP site, or maybe in an ISO image?**

(Note: I tried locating these *constrained* Python sources. Alas, no luck)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded and extracted the `Python sources` from https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.10/Python-2.7.10.tar.xz, and With `MagicISO`, I created an ISO image that can be mounted in the *Unixware VirtualBox.*